How to insert text into Trix editor after menu button is clicked?
I want to add custom button to Trix editor that would allow a user to enter url of video (YouTube, Vimeo) and then new  element will be inserted at current cursor position. The video ID would be encrypted.
I managed to add a button but I have troubles to use .insertString()
Trix.config.textAttributes.zzVideo = {
//    style: { color: "red" },
    parser: function(element) {
    
    var tEditor = document.querySelector("trix-editor")
    
    console.log(tEditor)
    console.log(tEditor.editor)
    console.log(element)
    console.log(element.editor)
    
    //tEditor.insertString("Hello")
 //   element.insertString("Hellow")
    
        return //element.style.color === "red"
    },
    inheritable: true
}

https://jsfiddle.net/radek/aL8ochdm/19/
If you also could guide me how to open a modal upon menu button click so user can enter the url it would be great.

The jsfiddle doesn't show the button you added. And it's not very clear what the app should do when you add the video URL.

@MarcoMerola Not sure what you mean. The buttons are there https://i.imgur.com/vXJdB2D.png. You are right it is not clear what needs to be done once video URL is added. Let's make is simple. I want to add 

to insert a text at cursor position inside trix event handler
addEventListener("trix-initialize", function(event) {
    event.target.editor.insertString("Hello")
}

or insert remotely
window.addEventListener("load",() => {
    const Trix = document.getElementsByTagName('trix-editor')[0];
    Trix.editor.insertString("Hello");
});

if you are going to embed a video it's better to try Trix.Attachment because the HTML inside a content attachment is not subject to Trix’s document conversion rules and will be rendered as-is.
addEventListener("trix-initialize", function(event) {
   const attachment = new Trix.Attachment({ content: "<b>HTML embed content</b>" })
   event.target.editor.insertAttachment(attachment);
});

for opening a modal and bind click event please first read this answer

add a html button to the toolbar with two attribute data-trix-attribute="FOO" data-trix-action="DOO"

add a html dialog inside <div class="trix-dialogs" data-trix-dialogs> withinsertAdjacentHTML ( copy the link dialog html code from toolbar.js )

set these attribute of the dialog same as the button data-trix-dialog="DOO" and data-trix-dialog-attribute="FOO"

set these attribute of the button located inside dialog that you want to attach event data-trix-action="x-NAME" data-trix-method="setAttribute"


then you can attach event on x-NAME ( x- prefix is mandatory )
document.addEventListener("trix-action-invoke", function(event) {
       if(event.actionName === "x-NAME"){
            // TODO 
            //document.querySelector('.trix-dialogs .trix-dialog--DIALOGNAME .trix-input') access to input value
       
});

the data-trix-method="setAttribute" invoke a method located in toolbar_controller.js, you can try other methods as well. ( like hideDialog or resetDialogInputs )
 setAttribute(dialogElement) {
    const attributeName = getAttributeName(dialogElement)
    const input = getInputForDialog(dialogElement, attributeName)
    if (input.willValidate && !input.checkValidity()) {
      input.setAttribute("data-trix-validate", "")
      input.classList.add("trix-validate")
      return input.focus()
    } else {
      this.delegate?.toolbarDidUpdateAttribute(attributeName, input.value)
      return this.hideDialog()
    }
  }

for better understanding of how Trix works check StimulusJS

I need to study your answers. Thank you so much for them.

You're welcome, let me know if I can help for any further

You need to use tEditor2.editor.insertString("Hello"); to insert plain text.
For more information:
Inserting Text and Files: https://github.com/basecamp/trix#inserting-and-deleting-text
Custom Toolbar Actions: https://github.com/basecamp/trix/wiki/Configuration#toolbar -> Invoke External Action
Here is a working example:
addEventListener("trix-initialize", function(event) {
    var videoButtonHTML = '<button id="myVideoButton" data-trix-action="x-log" type="button" data-trix-attribute="zzVideo">VideO</button>';
    
    event.target.toolbarElement.
    querySelector(".trix-button-group").
    insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", videoButtonHTML)
    
    document.addEventListener("trix-action-invoke", function(event) {
        if(event.actionName === "x-log"){
            // open modal here
            var tEditor2 = document.querySelector("trix-editor");
            tEditor2.editor.insertString("Hello");
        }
    })
 })

The Link input dialog is defined here: https://github.com/basecamp/trix/blob/beabac297c7a29220af2c3247c531d14a6fca971/src/trix/config/toolbar.js#L38
But I don't think you can open your own by default.
I use bootstrap to create modals, these can be opened from the click event listener.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/modal/

the issue is actually with the library and / or it's version and maybe different browsers. More details here https://stackoverflow.com/q/78802380/250422

I do not think I can accept your answers but I gave you the bounty. Thank you for your help
