Issue with loading js library - unpkg.com v cdnjs.cloudflare.com - inside DOMContentLoaded event
I was having an issue that I was not able to use .insertString("Hello") method of Trix editor. I was 100% following instructions of official documentation https://github.com/basecamp/trix#inserting-and-deleting-text
I found out that the issue is the location of Trix library I was using.
If Trix is loaded from https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com everything works fine but unpkg.com
Could someone please explain how come such issue is happening of the code is inside DOMContentLoaded event? I thought that load event would solve it but the javascript code inserting text is not working with load event at all.


/* what the newly created button does */

// document.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    // Your code to run since DOM is loaded and ready
     
     var element2 = document.querySelector("trix-editor")
element2.editor  // is a Trix.Editor instance
element2.editor.insertString("Hello2")
     
    });
    

//var element = document.querySelector("trix-editor")
//element.editor  // is a Trix.Editor instance
//const editor = document.querySelector('trix-editor').editor
//const length = element.editor.getDocument().toString().length
//console.log(length)
//element.editor.setSelectedRange(length - 1)
// Insert “Hello” at the beginning of the document
//element.editor.setSelectedRange([0, 0])
//element.editor.insertString("Hello")
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/trix@2.1.3/dist/trix.css">
<!--    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/trix@2.1.3/dist/trix.umd.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/trix/1.3.0/trix.js"></script>-->
  
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/trix/1.3.0/trix.js"></script>

  <input id="x" value="Editor content goes here" type="hidden" name="content">
  <trix-editor input="x"></trix-editor>



Original JSFiddle
UPDATE
The issue happens only in firefox. I created a bug report https://github.com/basecamp/trix/issues/1173

In your code you're using version 2.1.3 from unpkg, whereas the cloudflare version is 1.3.0. Major versions (1->2) tend to include breaking changes. Make sure you're reading the correct version of the documentation, or the library source code itself if that wasn't properly updated.

@l3l_aze you are right. I did not notice that.

It happens - I recently spent a week trying to fix a bug that was caused by just changing the value of a variable, and looked everywhere but there first. Lol.

EDIT: Discussion of a timing error has been added to the end of this answer
Trix 2.0.8
The Trix getting started guide uses Trix version 2.0.8 loading

CSS from https://unpkg.com/trix@2.0.8/dist/trix.css
mns.js from https://unpkg.com/trix@2.0.8/dist/trix.umd.min.js

This seemed to work fine, including inserting Hello2 into the edit area as shown in the post, but with a warning generated on the console by FireFox:

⚠️ Layout was forced before the page was fully loaded. If stylesheets are not yet loaded this may cause a flash of unstyled content. stylesheets-manager.js:664:11

I could live with the warning, but it's not great. [Edit: see Potential Timing Error below.]
Trix 2.1.3
The package.json file on GitHub shows 2.1.3 as the version value. Changing 2.0.8 to 2.1.3  in the link and script tags to load the later version produced the same results obtained from 2.0.8 above,

Potential Timing Error
Test code for this answer ran in successfully in FireFox but fails as a stack snippet:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><meta charset="utf-8">

   <title>trix</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/trix@2.1.3/dist/trix.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/trix@2.1.3/dist/trix.umd.min.js"></script>

<!-- text insertion when ready: -->

<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    // Your code to run since DOM is loaded and ready
     
     var element2 = document.querySelector("trix-editor")
     element2.editor  // is a Trix.Editor instance
     element2.editor.insertString("Hello2")
     
    })
</script>
</head>
<body>

 <input id="x" value="Editor content goes here" type="hidden" name="content">
 <trix-editor input="x"></trix-editor>

</body>
</html>



Run the above snippet to check it fails with console output:

TypeError: element2.editor is undefined

While I'd like to hand wave this away as a stack snippet error, I can't explain why accessing element2 after all event processing for DOMContentLoaded has completed by using a timer works as expected:


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    // Your code to run since DOM is loaded and ready (REALLY?)
     
     function doLater() {
       var element2 = document.querySelector("trix-editor")
       element2.editor  // is a Trix.Editor instance
       element2.editor.insertString("Hello2")    
     }
     setTimeout( doLater, 100);
});
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/trix@2.1.3/dist/trix.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/trix@2.1.3/dist/trix.umd.min.js"></script>

 <input id="x" value="Editor content goes here" type="hidden" name="content">
 <trix-editor input="x"></trix-editor>



This concerns me as I experienced the same error multiple times during testing and, while I assumed I had made some typographic errors or something, now I'm not so sure.
If you continue to have problems outside of stack snippets on SO, I recommend checking if there are any open known issues documented for Trix.

The issue happens only in firefox. I created a bug report https://github.com/basecamp/trix/issues/1173

Please consider adding a link to this post on the Trix issue to provide further information

the trix editor certainly works in firefox, but the potential of timing errors in setting the editor property of trix-editor elements needs to be definitively ruled out.

